# Upper bounds for the quantum fisher information?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, estimation

**Background:**

The quantum fisher information can be used to lower bound the variance, when estimating a parameter $\Theta$.
This estimation can be decomposed into three steps.

1. The initial state $\rho_0$
2. The encoding process, discribed by a CPTP map $M_\Theta$
3. The Messurement $\{E_m\}$ discribed by a POVM

The QFI allready contains an optimization about all possible POVMs.

**My questions:**

1. Is there an upperbound for the optimization over all possible
   initial states $\max_{\rho_0} QFI_{M_{\Theta}}(\rho_0)$ ?
2. Is there an upperbound for the optimization over all seprable
   initial states $\max_{\rho_0\in \text{SEP}}
       QFI_{M_{\Theta}}(\rho_0)$ ?
3. Are there other special cases, where bounds are known?

Comment: posts should include a single question. You can open multiple posts to ask each specific question (being as specific as possible as to what exactly the question is etc)